# serve react frontend and php backend on same domain with nginx

Tags: symfony, nginx, nginx-location

I have a React frontend and a Symfony backend I'm trying to serve on the same domain. The React frontend needs to serve assets if they exist otherwise fallback to serve `index.html`.

I'd like to serve the php Symfony app when `/api` is in the request uri. Similar to the React app, I need all requests to go to the `index.php` file.

The frontend is being served correctly but not the api. I get a 404 from nginx when i hit `/api` in the browser.

I feel like i'm close but for some reason nginx doesn't have the correct `$document_root`. I'm adding a header(`X-script`) to test what the variables are and I'm getting the following:

```
X-script: /usr/share/nginx/html/index.php
```

Here's my nginx config.

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    index index.html index.htm;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/my-site.com.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/my-site.com-error.log error;

    charset utf-8;

    location /api {
        root /var/www/my-site.com/backend;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
    }
    location / {
        root /var/www/my-site.com/frontend;
        try_files $uri /index.html;
    }
    location ~* \.php$ {
        add_header X-script "$document_root$fastcgi_script_name" always;
        try_files $fastcgi_script_name =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param HTTPS off;
    }
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The web root of a Symfony 4 project must include the `public` subfolder. I am not using NGINX but I think this is the correct configuration:

```
location /api {
    root /var/www/my-site.com/backend/public;
```

Comment: hey thanks but that's not the problem. i took symfony out of the equation and it still didn't work. `/var/www/my-site.com/backend/index.php` exists and just has `phpinfo();` in it but it's still not being served.

Answer (score 1):

In the following vhost, the most important changes I made are :

- commented out `index` directive in server block : it is handled directly in locations blocks
- added a slash after `location /api/` and remove unnecessary `$uri/` in the same *api location block*
- moved the php_fpm logic to `index.php` location block : you want all requests to be passed to front controller in Symfony app
- For the same reason, moved the 404 logic to a general php block, which will handle any other php file request

---

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/my-site.com.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/my-site.com-error.log error;

    charset utf-8;

    location /api/ {
        root /var/www/my-site.com/backend;
        try_files $uri  /index.php$is_args$args;
    }

    location / {
        root /var/www/my-site.com/frontend;
        try_files $uri /index.html;
    }

    location ~ ^/index\.php(/|$) {
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT $realpath_root;
        fastcgi_param HTTPS off;

        internal;
    }

    # return 404 for all other php files not matching the front controller
    # this prevents access to other php files you don't want to be accessible.
    location ~ \.php$ {
        return 404;
    }
}
```

Last, I bet you'll have to add symfony public folder into `api location block` root directive.

This vhost was tested fine on my localhost with following tree.

```
api_test
  - backend
    - index.php
  - frontend
    - index.html
```

I can successfully access to

- `backend/index.php` from api_test.dv/api
- `frontend/index.html` from api_test.dv/

Answer (score 0):

Kojos answer is excellent, but to make it completely functional a root directive needs to be added under server or an error message “primary script unknown” will be observed. This is almost always related to a wrongly set SCRIPT_FILENAME in the nginx fastcgi_param directive.

```
# Nginx configuration
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    server_name ${NGINX_HOST};

    root /var/www/html/backend/public;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access_log.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log error;

    charset utf-8;

    location / {
        root /var/www/html/frontend/build;
        try_files $uri /index.html;
    }

    location /api {
        alias /var/www/html/backend/public;
        try_files $uri /index.php$is_args$args;
    }

    location ~ ^/index\.php(/|$) {
        fastcgi_pass php-fpm:9000;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT $realpath_root;

        internal;
    }

    # return 404 for all other php files not matching the front controller
    # this prevents access to other php files you don't want to be accessible.
    location ~ \.php$ {
        return 404;
    }
}
```

Comment: it return me an empty page and it also doesn't show any error in log